# URL rewrite based on PHP Variable

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use rewrite rules depending on a php variable?
for example, i got 10 websites with 10 domains. each website got a "config.php". Inside this file, there is a variable called $city.

can i rewrite the url in this style?

pseudocode:

```
if ($city == 'berlin') {
page.php = page-berlin.php
}
```

Comment: You may have the wrong idea about what "rewriting" means. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/476

Comment: thanks for your comment. when rewriting is the wrong solution for my problem, what should i use instead to "rename" files dynamically? xyz.tld/page1.php to xyz.tld/page1-berlin.php for example

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/2071847) in which changes the url of the browser without refreshing the page, it can solve your problem if it is just the look of the url you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple routing script that all of your domains are pointed to. Using $_SERVER['server_name'] you then loading the required config file, which has the file it needs to include to give you the required output, or it loads in the config.php file, which sets a constant using define('CITY', 'BERLIN') which the rest of your script can use.

This isn't rewriting, but it should work for your situation.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i dont really understand it. example: on "xyz-dubai.tld all files (page1.php, page2.php) should renamed to page1-dubai.php, page2-dubai.php. on xyz-berlin.tld the page1 should renamed to page1-berlin.php

Comment: When I get home later I will comment my answer with proper code - I just noticed the question in new and didn't have time yesterday earlier.